# When does combat end?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounters

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/141104/49393) says that the (enemy) bugbear is part of the combat when he knows about it.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79200/49393) says you can only be surprised at the beginning of combat.

Could the unnoticed bugbear wait until every enemy the party knows about is dead, and then attack to surprise them?
Basically, when does an encounter end, and when does another start?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate) on [When does one leave turn based action if you are in a hostile area](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104614/when-does-one-leave-turn-based-action-if-you-are-in-a-hostile-area)

Comment: After further review, this very much looks like a duplicate. If it isn't, please clarify the difference and we can reopen this.

Comment: @NautArch I'm not so sure. That question seems heavily focused on the time scale and round by round tracking. However this question is focused on combat in general ending and the two are only the same if you argue that combat is always tracked by the round or that when you stop tracking by the round combat ends. I'm not sure that logical leap is small enough to justify a duplicate.

Comment: Can you clarify that the Bugbear is an "enemy"? I think it's safe to assume they're not a PC who's going to surprise and attack the corpses of the dead opponents, but, to be honest, people ask all kinds of unusual questions here on RPG SE. Is the Bugbear PC or NPC attacking the PCs?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Possibly - but that's why i'm asking OP if that does answer the question. It could be a new question if combat doesn't equal turn based order for them. But this question does seem to be asking when does initiative end and another begin in order for the bug bear to gain their ability? THe duped question is also asking when combat ends in a potentially hostile area (which is what this is).

Comment: This makes me feel like "What is the Start of Combat?" would be valuable.

Comment: @NautArch nitsua60's first comment answers this question, not his answer.

Comment: @SpearCarrier.no2 I've asked Nitsua60 to fold that comment into the answer. I still think it applies to the question asked (which i still think is the same as your question.) But let me know if you think the question (and not the answer) is basically the same or not (and why not if it isn't.)